# Filter newGraphPathRequest "me/friends by name

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph

Is there a way to Filter the Graph result from Facebook ( me/friends ) by name?

I would like to add a simple search function in my Android app so that a user can search though his Friends and show only this result. I think it is no good way to fetch the complete list of friends and filter this later.

This is a short snipped how i use at the moment

```
private Request createRequest(Session session) {
        Request request = Request.newGraphPathRequest(session, "me/friends", null);

        Set<String> fields = new HashSet<String>();
        String[] requiredFields = new String[] { "id", "username","name", "picture" };
        fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(requiredFields));

        Bundle parameters = request.getParameters();
        parameters.putString("fields", TextUtils.join(",", fields));
        if(!searchActive) {
            parameters.putString("limit", limit);
            parameters.putString("offset", offset);
        }

        request.setParameters(parameters);

        return request;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I moved my code to the Serverside and use the version v1.0 of Facebook and call with android my own api to search my friends.